# What does this injected perl script do?

Tags: perl

This perl script was found (presumed injected) on a Wordpress website. Could someone please explain the basic overview of what it is doing?

**UPDATE:**
The questions is being marked down as "Too Broad" so should I ask what is the script doing *exactly* rather than asking for a "basic overview"?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
chomp(my @from=<DATA>);

require POSIX;
my %seen_dev_inode=();

# Fix path separators
(my $path_sep=POSIX::getcwd())=~s#^(?:\w+:)?(.).*#$1#;

sub du_r {
  my ($f) = @_;
  my @s=lstat($f); 
  unless(@s) {
    warn "lstat() failed for $f: $!";
  }
  if($s[1] and $seen_dev_inode{$s[0]}{$s[1]}) {
    return 0; # Already seen.
  }
  $seen_dev_inode{$s[0]}{$s[1]}=1;
  my $size = $s[12] ? 512*$s[12] : $s[7];
  $size||=0;
  if(not(-l $f) and -d $f) {
    my $owd = POSIX::getcwd();
    my @dents;
    if(opendir(DIR, "$f")) {
      @dents = grep {!m/^(\.\.?)$/} readdir DIR;
      closedir DIR;
    }
    $size+=du_r(join($path_sep, $f, $_)) for @dents;
  }
  return $size;
}
if($^X=~/[.]dll$/) {
  print "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n";
}
print "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n";
@from = map {s#/#$path_sep#g; $_} @from;
#
printf("%.0fM\n", du_r($_)/(1024*1024)) for @from;
close(DATA) and unlink($0);
__DATA__
../
```

Comment: The close reason "Too Broad" is defined as: "too broad: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs." 
Normally 'what does this script do' counts, but I think this one is simple enough in what it's doing.

Answer (score 3):

Look like it traverses up a level `../` from `<DATA>` and then uses `stat` and traverses to count file sizes. Returns that as an approximate web page format. And then deletes itself.

So probably more a 'does this exploit work' sort of test, rather than doing anything directly harmful.